# Nest PHP variable inside Javascript onClick Method

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code:

```
function count_words_display($speech, $articleid){

    if (str_word_count($speech)>200){

    $speech_short = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $speech), 0, 100)).'...<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction("'.$articleid.'","'.$speech.'")">';
    print $speech_short;
}
else{

    print $speech;
    }
}
```

I intend on getting output similar to this:

```
<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction('24','Play')";>
```

However, I end up with this:

```
<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction("24","Play")";>
```

Resulting in this error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

Comment: first, you have to use single quote in your function parameters (onClick attribute) ....

Comment: I'm forced to use double quotes so that I can concatenate the php variables into the onClick function

Comment: So use single quote on your onClick attribute... you cannot have a string like this... it's an ABCs

Comment: The onclick is generated by the function below; using double or single quotes isn't the problem per say:  $speech_short = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $speech), 0, 100)).'...<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction("'.$articleid.'","'.$speech.'")">';
    print $speech_short;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'...<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction(\''.$articleid.'\',\''.$speech.'\')">';
```

Comment: I get this: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: @RaymondMwaura does your `$speech` variable have a line break in it?

Comment: Yes, it's an entire paragraph.

Comment: If you just copy-paste the line I wrote, overwriting the same string from your original code, it should work. Unless there is a line break in $speech as @forrestmid suggested.

Comment: @RaymondMwaura Try to cleanse the $speech variable with `$speech = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $speech );` and see if that solves the issue. As well, since you have the article ID do you really need to put the `$speech` into the onclick attribute at all?

Comment: I cleaned it up using this `$speech_preg = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $speech);` However, it only works on a few paragraphs($speeches), on some I get this `'' literal not terminated before end of script` The speech is used by the onClick to insert the speech inside a div block using this `function myFunction(article_id, article_full) {

    var article_body = document.getElementById(article_id);
    article_body.innerHTML = article_full;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I took your initial statements and ideas and kind of ran with it a bit.

The problem you were having is that you were trying to pass a giant string to a javascript function but you couldn't really control what was going to be in the string so things got screwy.

When creating the javascript onClick code, I pass a javascript variable instead of the whole string.  I set the value of that variable at the beginning of the html so it will be available when they click on it.

Check this out:

```
<?php
//array for holding all articles 
$articles = array();

//the article in question
$article = new stdClass;
//id of the article
$article->id = 345;

//full text of the article
$article->fullText = "
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus, orci a lacinia ornare, magna ante tincidunt odio, a molestie velit libero sit amet massa. Nullam volutpat diam et tellus sodales cursus. Vestibulum tempor in eros vel tristique. Vestibulum varius purus in ultrices tincidunt. Morbi mi orci, faucibus vitae tempor sed, sollicitudin ut sem. Etiam porta sem justo, et dapibus ipsum accumsan sed. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum id turpis mattis, rutrum dui non, varius magna. Phasellus rhoncus auctor dapibus. Ut nunc erat, sodales eget consectetur nec, interdum sit amet libero. Cras eget dui ante. Aliquam sit amet nisl vitae libero posuere hendrerit. Aliquam porta at arcu nec sodales. Pellentesque sapien nisl, facilisis eget ornare id, convallis eget erat.
Nunc cursus porttitor aliquet. Mauris sapien nibh, fermentum in turpis in, ornare malesuada nulla. Aliquam varius turpis felis, non imperdiet ante ornare eu. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla eget viverra nisl. In nunc sapien, vehicula quis tristique commodo, congue eget felis. Vestibulum vehicula velit eros. Fusce nec neque sed leo ornare mollis ut vitae urna. Suspendisse vitae nisi ut nulla egestas gravida.
Integer et pretium ligula, vitae rutrum odio. Proin condimentum lectus et odio suscipit, ut pharetra justo luctus. Integer iaculis, tortor eu sodales volutpat, nibh nisi porttitor elit, et dapibus enim odio sed augue. Praesent nec turpis non mauris tincidunt interdum non in neque. Vestibulum sagittis leo magna, in malesuada dui viverra vel. Morbi ornare urna ac est pharetra, at ornare tortor ullamcorper. Pellentesque eget libero felis. Ut scelerisque nunc at pharetra ultricies. Nullam pretium sapien ex, at viverra ligula venenatis rutrum. Proin molestie hendrerit nunc non venenatis.
";
//short form of the article
if (str_word_count($article->fullText)>200){
    $article->shortText = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $article->fullText), 0, 100)).'...<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction(\''.$article->id.'\',fullArticle_'.$article->id.');">';
}else{
    $article->shortText = $article->fullText;
}
//javascript code that needs to be run for each article
$article->javascriptVariable = 'var fullArticle_'.$article->id.' = `'. str_replace('`',"",$article->fullText) .'`;';
//save this article in our list of articles.
array_push($articles, $article);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Speech thingy</title>
        <script>
            <?php 
                //set variables in the javascript to hold the full text
                foreach ($articles as $article){
                    echo $article->javascriptVariable . "\n";
                }
            ?>;

            function myFunction(article_id, article_full) { 
                var article_body = document.getElementById(article_id); 
                article_body.innerHTML = article_full;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            foreach ($articles as $article){
                echo '<div class="article-excerpt">';
                echo $article->shortText;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="'.$article->id.'">';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another idea would be to just put the full text in a hidden div and then show the appropriate div when they click it.  Doing this would avoid the need to pass any full text information via javascript function.  The only downside is that Google Search might lower your ranking for having duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Find can find a way to hide the original text though. I never knew about `stdClass`, I'll look into that some more. You can check out how I FINALLY(after lots of Deathcore to soothe myself) did it below.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Code

```
function count_words_display($speech, $articleid){

 if (str_word_count($speech)>200){

    $speech_short = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $speech), 0, 100)).'...<input type="button" id="read" value="Read more" onclick="myFunction('.$articleid.')">';
        print "<div id = 'short".$articleid."'>".$speech_short."</div>";

        print "<div id = 'long".$articleid."' style='display:none'>".$speech."</div>";  
 }
 else{

    print $speech;
 }
}
```

The JavaScript Code

```
function myFunction(article_id) {
 var x = document.getElementById('short'+article_id);
 var y = document.getElementById('long'+article_id);
 if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
   }

if (y.style.display === 'block') {
    y.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    y.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```